# What is the best practice to pass parameters from Controller to a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new in AngularJS

In my angular app, I have a directive and a controller. I need that my controller send options of any kinds of configurations, including callback methods.

My directive is an Element that implements one button to post data into an webservice. My desire is that my controller send a url for this "post" method and send a callback method, that have to be called after this "post" in my directive.

How is the best way to do this?
Is it a good practice to send callback methods like this?

Comment: you need to use a isolated scope with a two way binded scope variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually specify the parameters in the tags of the element. For instance:

```
<my-directive my-service="someService" my-callback="someCallback" />
```

Inside my directive I use the $parse function to read/set these values:

```
var getService = $parse(attrs.myService),
    setService = getService.assign,
    service = getService(scope);
```